# Keyboard shortcuts in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, keyboard

I'm trying to write some code that allows users to interact with an LWC component using keyboard short cuts (Shift + N, Shift + S). Using the window.addEventListener() works, and the shortcuts do what they need to do, but unfortunately it also affects anything that might sit on top of the page, such as chatter, by continueing to listen for the shortcuts, even if the component isn't in focus.

I've tried doing:

```
this.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
this.template.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
let container = this.template.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
```

But none of these work properly. I can get them to trigger if I'm hammering the keys as I press a link on the component, which makes me think that it gets focus for a split second, long enough to fire the event.

```
 <div onkeydown={handleKeyPress}>
```

This doesn't work either, and behaves the same as the above attempts. Any suggestions?